# Cannot rearrange arrays in accordance with another array that has been sorted

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this code:

```
<?php
   $sort = array(1.5, 3.4, 2.1, 4.9, 5.7, 6.3);
   sort($sort);
   $tampil=array('abc','hoho','hah','something','lol','nice');
   $tampil2=array('wait','wush','wicked','who','why','what');

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($sort); $i++) {
       echo $i.'_<strong>'.$sort[$i].'</strong>'; 
       echo '_'.$tampil[$i].'_';
       echo $tampil2[$i].' <br />';
   }
?>
```

The result is:

```
0_1.5_abc_wait 
1_2.1_hoho_wush 
2_3.4_hah_wicked 
3_4.9_something_who 
4_5.7_lol_why 
5_6.3_nice_what
```

What I want is that the `$tampil[$i]` will be displayed in accordance with the sorted `$sort` , and so will the `$tampil2[$i]` (`$i`'s follows the `$i` in `$sort`).
It's like this, how I wish it appear:

```
0_1.5_abc_wait 
1_2.1_hah_wicked //$tampil and $tampil2's positions change by the sorted $sort
2_3.4_hoho_wush
3_4.9_something_who 
4_5.7_lol_why 
5_6.3_nice_what
```

I tried to do `multisort` and `foreach` thing to address this issue. But it seems to be a difficult logic for me to solve. And I don't seem to find solutions by querying in Google and StackOverFlow with the title above.
Need help. :) Thanks..

Comment: any reason you're using 3 separate arrays?

Comment: I'm in a project to build a meta-search engine, so I use different arrays for the title, the description (snippet), the link etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for! [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort($sort, $tampil, $tampil2);
```

`array_multisort` sort first array and reindexing other arrays according to the first

#### Result

```
0_1.5_abc_wait 
1_2.1_hah_wicked 
2_3.4_hoho_wush 
3_4.9_something_who 
4_5.7_lol_why 
5_6.3_nice_what
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sort = array(1.5, 3.4, 2.1, 4.9, 5.7, 6.3);
$sort_dup = $sort;
sort($sort_dup);

$tampil=array('abc','hoho','hah','something','lol','nice');
$tampil2=array('wait','wush','wicked','who','why','what');

$i = 0;
foreach($sort_dup as $sorted) {
   $key = array_search($sorted, $sort);
   echo $i."_".$sorted."_".$tampil[$key]."_".$tampil2[$key]."<br />";
}

?>
```

Well, I have created a duplicate and sorted that one. While looping, it gets key from the original array and print out the values of other 2 array's elements. It has the same logic and working as `array_multisort()` PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

sort like this

```
<?php
$sort = array(1.5, 3.4, 2.1, 4.9, 5.7, 6.3);
$tampil=array('abc','hoho','hah','something','lol','nice');
$tampil2=array('wait','wush','wicked','who','why','what');
array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $tampil, $tampil2);
var_dump($sort, $tampil, $tampil2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you format your array like this, you can use `ksort` on the items, then loop through them easily.

**Note:** Your key's `1.5, 3.4, etc.` need to be strings for this to work.

Like this:

```
<?php
$sort = array(
        "1.5" => array(
        "abc",
        "wait"
    ), 
    "3.4" => array(
        "hoho",
        "wush"
    ), 
    "2.1" => array(
        "hah",
        "wicked"
    ), 
    "4.9" => array(
        "something",
        "who"
    ), 
    "5.7" => array(
        "lol",
        "why"
    ), 
    "6.3" => array(
        "nice",
        "what"
    )
);

ksort($sort);


$i = 0;
foreach($sort as $key => $value){
    echo "{$i}_{$key}_{$value[0]}_{$value[1]}\n";
    $i++;
}
```

The final output will look like this:

```
0_1.5_abc_wait
1_2.1_hah_wicked
2_3.4_hoho_wush
3_4.9_something_who
4_5.7_lol_why
5_6.3_nice_what
```